# Sketches, the realized sketch and a model

Tags: category-theory, morphism

I have a problem [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sketch) with this statement in Chapter 2,Details:

> In particular, $T$ is realized if and only if its identity functor is a model.

Namely, I do not know how the identity functor arises and between which categories it leads ?

Is it $id:T\to T$ or $id:C\to C$ ?

How do follow both directions of the above **iff** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ is realised if and only if the identity functor on the category $T$ is a model. If $\mathrm{Id}_T : T \to T$ is a model, then each (co)cone in $T$ is sent to a (co)limit (co)cone in $T$, which means each (co)cone must have been (co)limiting in the first place. Conversely, if each (co)cone in $T$ is (co)limiting, then the identity will send each (co)cone to a (co)limiting (co)cone by definition, which means $\mathrm{Id}_T$ is a model.